# Font colour (color) used in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: ssms

It is possible to change the default font colour (color) used in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) in the messages pane output, via a SQL print command?

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT 'The database update succeeded'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT 'The database update failed'
GO
```

I.e

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's a bit of an old post, but if you still want to be able to display your text in red:
use the built in RAISERROR function. You can set the severity of the error and that will determine if it outputs your text in black or red. For example:

```
raiserror('Your error message', 10, 0)
```

Will display the error with just the black font color

```
raiserror('Your error message', 11, 0)
```

Will display the error with a red font color

Message severity of 10 or lower will use black font color, 11 or higher will use red font color.

For completion: message severity of 20 or higher will stop executing the rest of the script, and if you use a message severity of 19 or higher you have to call the raiserror function with the log option, like so:

```
 raiserror('Your error message', 20, 0) with log
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I really don't know why the accepted "answer" that only states, "um...I don't know, sorry" was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of SQL Server, the RAISERROR function is not available, but you can use THROW instead. It works similarly. However, it is a bit more extensive. For details, please refer to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16